# Select all Classes except children of ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is my `html`:

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="elem_tec"> 
    <li class="elem_tec"> 
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
    <li class="elem_tec"> 
    <li class="elem_tec"> 
</ul>
<ul id="list3">
    <li class="elem_tec"> 
    <li class="elem_tec"> 
</ul>
```

I'd like to select all `.elem_tec` but the `elem_tec` elements in `#list1`.
I have tried: `:not(#list1) .elem_tec` but it does not work.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
ul:not(#list1) li.elem_tec{
    color: red;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yv5q4gvm/33/)**

Answer (score 1):

You  should try like this  and close `li` also -

```css
 ul:not(#list1) li{
        color: green;
    }
```

```html
    <ul id="list1">
        <li class="elem_tec"> 90 </li>
        <li class="elem_tec"> 90 </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list2">
        <li class="elem_tec"> 90 </li>
        <li class="elem_tec"> 90 </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list3">
        <li class="elem_tec"> 90 </li>
        <li class="elem_tec">90 </li> 
    </ul>
```

Comment: They don't need to be closed. There is even less of a point in closing them if you're going to do it so haphazardly, leaving unnecessary whitespace in inconsistent places.